# extracting method name from linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

How can I get the name of the first method called from an expression in C#?  Something like the fictional *MethodUtils.NameFromExpression()* below:

```
Expression<Action<string>> expr = s => s.Trim();
Assert.AreEqual("Trim", MethodUtils.NameFromExpression(expr));
```

Ideally any util method would be written/overloaded in such a way that it could take expressions for any of the Action or Func delegate types.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I found an answer (below) but would still like input as to whether this is a good solution or whether there already exists a way of doing this in the BCL.

Comment: Check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412182/get-the-names-of-interface-methods-strong-typed/32245698#32245698
HTH..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A bit of digging with the debugger and I've answered my own question:

```
public static class MethodUtils
{
    public static string NameFromExpression(LambdaExpression expression)
    {
        MethodCallExpression callExpression = 
            expression.Body as MethodCallExpression;

        if(callExpression == null)
        {                
            throw new Exception("expression must be a MethodCallExpression");
        }

        return callExpression.Method.Name;
    }
}
```

Any comments on this implementation?

Comment: Exactly what I was about to suggest!

Comment: "Any comments on this implementation?" ==> Check my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412182/get-the-names-of-interface-methods-strong-typed/32245698#32245698